# How to display validation error summary at top in MVC5 with bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am trying to show the validation error summary at top and want to give some style but unfortunately when i am trying to click on form submit button, It displays the errors but with each control rather than at top.

I want to decorate the built-in validation summary rather than creating my own JavaScript validation functions.

What i am trying to do is, please see my code.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });

        function submitForm() {
            if ($("#frmR").valid()) {
                var form = $("#frmR").serialize();
                $.post("/Portal/Registration/RegisterP", form, function (msg) {

                });
            }
      }

    function Shift() {
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    }
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #edf8f7;
    /* background-image: none; */
    border: 1px solid #8dc6cd;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px\9;
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio" i] {
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
}

input[type="radio" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio" i], input[type="checkbox" i] {
    background-color: initial;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}

input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}

input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}

input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    color: #6b7b8a;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #54667a;
    line-height: 22px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
label>input[type="radio"]{
  vertical-align: -30%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js" > </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" > </script>
</head>
<body>
<form  id="frmR" action="#" method="post">    
                     <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
                     <div class="col-xs-6 remove-padding">
                         <h4>Patient's Appointment Type</h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-6">
                         <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" onclick="submitForm(); return false;" class="btn-primarySmall pull-right">
                             Register
                         </button>
                    </div>
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-xs-12">
                                 <div class="col-xs-12">
                                     <div>
                                         <label class="">Type</label>
                                         <label><input type="radio" name="Type" checked="" value="Walk-In">Walk-In</label>
                                         <label><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Telephonic">Telephonic</label>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-xs-12 remove-padding">
                                     <hr />
                                     <h4>Patient's Personal Information</h4>
                                     <hr />
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                         <label>First Name<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                                         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="vFirstName" id="vFirstName" required="required" />
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't edit to incorporate the code from the solution into your question.  It's pointless and the answer below no longer makes sense if the correct code is already built into the question.   Rolled it back.  You also wouldn't put `.validate()` inside of the `submit` function... it's used to initialize the plugin on page load and would not get called every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `errorPlacement` funtion of jQuery Validation to decorate and display all errors at top:

You need to add bellow html above form

```
<ul class="errorList"></ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#frmR").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element = element.closest('li');
        element = element.children(':first-child');
        error.insertBefore(element);
        error.addClass('message');
        $(function() {                                 // my function
            var errorIndex = $(error).index('div');
            var errorId = 'errordiv' + errorIndex.toString();
            $(error).attr('id', errorId);
            $('.errorList').append('<li><a href="#' + errorId + '">' + $(error).text() + '</a></li>');
        });    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bharatsing. Am i doing in the correct way. i used these line of code in ready event.
  var validator = $('form').data('validator');
            validator.settings.errorPlacement = function (error, element) {     
// your line of code           
                    });                
            };

but it throwing an error .
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Comment: I have edited my answer. you need to add function in $("#frmR").validate(); function

Comment: thank you. now see in above post, it is working. thank you

Comment: What a roundabout way.  @user6306245, you can simply use the `errorLabelContainer` option which automatically takes care of all this.  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer